# ElasticSearch: restrict results but not facet counts

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I'm struggling writing an ElasticSearch query with facet counts. The query itself needs two conditions:

1. a condition which restricts the document set, excluded documents should not be used for the facet count.
2. a condition which restricts the result set but excluded documents should be part of the facet count.

Example documents:

```
{"user": "editor", "tag": "foo"}
{"user": "editor", "tag": "bar"}
```

query:

```
{
    "query" : { 
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {"term": {"user": "editor"} }
        }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : { "terms" : {"field" : "tag"} }
    }
}
```

The result of this query is ok, I see a facet count for tag foo+bar correctly. Now I'd like to extend the query so the results only display documents with tag "foo" BUT keep the facet count as before (so tag "bar" should also appear in the facet count).

For example if I modify the `constant_score` filter like this:

```
"filter": {
    "and": [{"term": {"user": "editor"}}, {"term": {"tag": "foo"}}]
}
```

then obviously only the tag "foo" will appear in the facet count so I need to add
the `{"term": {"tag": "foo"}}` filter somewhere else.

How do I do that in ElasticSearch?

Comment: i think that elasticsearch will automatically do exactly that. otherwise have a look at search-facet and the scope parameter http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html#_scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what [ES documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html) says:

> While search queries restrict both the returned documents and facet
>   counts, search filters restrict only returned documents — but not
>   facet counts.

Something like that might work:

```
{
    "query" : { 
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {"term": {"user": "editor"} }
        }
    },
    "filter" : {"term": {"tag": "foo"} },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : { "terms" : {"field" : "tag"} }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Just a minor syntax error `"filter: :` should be `"filter" :` (missing quote, double colon). Also the filter does not have to replicate the "user" term query.